# How do you place an image in the middle of a line of text

Tags: html, css

I have been struggling to try and place an image in the middle of a line of text.

"this is text **THIS IS THE IMAGE** this is text"

Any idea?

Comment: just `<p>tex text <img src="..." alt="" /> text text</p>`? if you don't have any special styles for image it should work just fine.

Comment: You can create three divs, and make it all left floated then on the middle div you put the image then the left div you put the left text, and on the right div you put the right text...

Answer (score 2):

The old non-standard `valign='ABSMIDDLE'` is massively deprecated.... Although it still works in every browser I know.

This should be a valid CSS workaround:

```
<img src="..." style="vertical-align:middle">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using CSS:

```
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want is this?

```
<div>
this is text <img src="..." style="display:inline"> this is text
</div>
```

Comment: The `img` element is inline by default.